# Usage of AddXmlDocComputed in an F# type provider

Tags: f#, type-providers

I have a type provider which provides a static property but the documentation is subject to change at recurring intervals throughout. I have the following property setup.

```
let prop = ProvidedProperty("Test", typeof<string>,
                            IsStatic = true,
                            GetterCode = fun args -> <@@ "Test" @@>)
```

I then tried to add some documentation to it with `AddXmlDocComputed` as follows

```
let GetDocumentation () = "Test documentation"

do prop.AddXmlDocComputed(GetDocumentation)
```

However, I get no text displayed in the Intellisense comments. I then raised an exception in the `GetDocumentation` function which is reflected in the intellisense through the addition of the `[<Note>]` and the message saying that it originated from the call to `GetDocumentation`. I also tried using `AddXmlDoc` and `AddXmlDocDelayed`, both of which added the documentation as expected.

So this leads to my question of does anyone have any experience using `AddXmlDocComputed` and why does my current implementation add no documentation to the property?

**Edit:**
I've now tried debugging a VS2013 instance and can see that the documentation is being called and the expected string is being passed through the type provider for that property, however, there is still no documentation appearing in the Intellisense window.

Comment: I've not used `AddXmlDocComputed` at all, I'm afraid. How is it supposed to differ in function from `AddXmlDocDelayed`?

Comment: When using `AddXmlDocDelayed`, the documentation seems to be cached even on a call to `Invalidate`. I was under the impression that a call to `AddXmlDocComputed` would lead to a change in the documentation should `Invalidate` be called.

Comment: Have you tried to debug this in ProvidedTypes.fs ?

Comment: I've not gone into ProvidedTypes.fs yet but that is definitely my next place to check

Answer (score 0):

I believe this to be a bug in `ProvidedTypes.fs`. The explanation is that the computed XML doc attribute is never actually returned when `GetCustomAttributesData()` in `type CustomAttributesImpl()`. Instead of returning the attribute as part of the array of attributes, it is added to an internal list of attributes (by accident I assume).

To fix the issue locally, replace the implementation with this code:

```
member __.GetCustomAttributesData() = 
    [| yield! customAttributesOnce.Force()
       match xmlDocAlwaysRecomputed with None -> () | Some f -> yield mkXmlDocCustomAttributeData (f())  |]
    :> IList<_>
```

I have issued a pull request on GitHub with the fix.

**Update**:

The fix has been merged into the master branch of [FSharp.TypeProviders.StarterPack](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.TypeProviders.StarterPack).